# Using Skip and Take to pick up alternate items in an array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a string array with the following items:

```
string s = "M,k,m,S,3,a,5,E,2,Q,7,E,8,J,4,Y,1,m,8,N,3,P,5,H";
 var items = s.split(',');
 var topThree = items.Take(3);
 var alternating1 = items.Skip(3).Take(1).Skip(1).Take(1).Skip(1).Take(1).Skip(1).Take(1);
```

The alternating1 variable has nothing in it and I think I understand why. After the Skip then Take it returns 1 item in it so it then tries to Skip(1) and Take(1) but there is nothing there.

Is there a way I can do this alternating pattern?

Comment: Is 's' always going to be a string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use the `Where` overload which takes an index:

```
var alternating = input.Where((value, index) => (index & 1) == 0);
```

Or to use `% 2` instead, equivalently:

```
var alternating = input.Where((value, index) => (index % 2) == 0);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that test be `(index & 1) == 0`? If not, why not?

Comment: A minor nitpick about style: wouldn't using `index % 2` be more indicative of the code's high-level purpose than `index & 1`? The purpose of the query is to return every other item, not perform bit-twiddling.

Comment: @LukeH: I habitually convert one to the other. I'll add another version though.

Comment: @LukeH if you want to be really clear: `static class Number { public static bool IsEven(int this value) { return (value % 1) == 0 } }` and `input.Where((value,index) => index.IsEven())`